# Where does Oracle SQL Developer store connections?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an application that I can't get connected to my Oracle Database 11g Express Edition. I created a test database in this edition, and I can connect to the database fine using Oracle SQL Developer, create tables, views etc. However, I'm having a hard time getting connected via my application. Where is the connection information? In what file? I wanted to compare my connection info with what is set up in the SQL Explorer's file. I found all the *.ora files and renamed them to see if I could find what file (through the process of elimination) the connections were stored in, but I wasn't successful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using? Are you using SQL developer that came with an installation of the database, or did you download the standalone?

Comment: Sorry!  I am using Windows 7 (64 bit machinr) abd I downloaded the standalone.

Comment: Installed in path: C:\Oracle\sqlDeveloper

Comment: ah, i found it!  I believe i found it on my own. It is stored in a file called connections.xml under \Users[User]\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\System\

When i renamed the file, all my connection info went away. I renamed it back, and it all came back. When i viewed the XML file, i found both test connection anliases, ports, usernames, roles, authentcation types, etc.

Comment: Is the app with which you're trying to connect 32 or 64 bits?

Answer (score 98):

It was in a slightly different location for me than those listed above

```
\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system3.2.20.09.87\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.4.37.59.48\connections.xml
```

Comment: Thanks!  It would be interesting to know what these Oracle people are thinking when they come up with a path like that!

Comment: or substitute the stuff up through "Roaming" with the %APPDATA% environment variable, optionally

Comment: ... and the Connection _Folders_ are stored here:  `\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system4.2.0.17.089.1709\o.sqldeveloper.12.2.1.17.89.1709\product-preferences.xml`

Comment: This file is a `json` now.

Answer (score 41):

Assuming you have lost these while upgrading versions like I did, follow these steps to restore:

1. Open SQL Developer
2. Right click on Connections
3. Chose Import Connections...
4. Click Browse (should open to your SQL Developer directory)
5. Drill down to "systemx.x.xx.xx" (replace x's with your previous version of SQL Developer)
6. Find and drill into a folder that has ".db.connection." in it (for me, it was in o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.4.37.59.48)
7. select connections.xml and click open

You should then see the list of connections that will be imported

Comment: This works but then I get the prompt 'Use a key to decrypt all passwords'.

What do we do here please? 

I would have thought the connections.xml file will have the details including passwords.

Comment: How to find decrypt Key . I am getting this too. "Use a key to decrypt all passwords".

Answer (score 13):

If you don't find the `connections.xml` then right-click on `Connections` in the Connections view of SQLDeveloper, and choose `Export connections`.

Comment: in more detail see http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/05/migrating-oracle-sql-developer-connections-with-passwords/

Answer (score 11):

It is stored in a file called connections.xml under

```
\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\System\
```

When I renamed the file, all my connection info went away. I renamed it back, and it all came back. When I viewed the XML file, I found both test connection aliases, ports, usernames, roles, authentication types, etc.

Answer (score 9):

In some versions, it stores it under

```
<installed path>\system\oracle.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.0.11.42.44
\IDEConnections.xml
```

Answer (score 6):

For OS X my connection.xml files are in

```
/Users/<username>/.sqldeveloper/system<sqldeveloper_version>/o.jdeveloper.db.connection.<oracle_version?>/
```

Answer (score 4):

With SQLDeveloper v19.1.0 on Windows, I found this **as a JSON file** in

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system<versionNumber>\o.jdeveloper.db.connection
```

The file name is `connections.json`

Answer (score 3):

I found mine in

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system2.1.1.64.45\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.2.36.55.30\connections.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

SqlDeveloper stores all the connections in a file named

```
connections.xml
```

In windows XP you can find the file in location

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\SQL Developer\systemX.X.X.X.X\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.X.X.X.X.X.X.X\connections.xml
```

In Windows 7 you will find it in location

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\systemX.X.X.X.X\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.X.X.X.X.X.X.X\connections.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have previously installed SQL Developer then it will store the connection details in the 'connection.xml' which will be located in below mentioned path.

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system3.1.07.42\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.4.37.59.48
```

Once you get that **'connection.xml'**
try to import it into SQLDeveloper by right clicking to CONNECTIONS.

Answer (score 2):

In a simpler way open search window and search for `connection.xml` gives a right click on that file and select open file/folder location.
Once you get that `connection.xml` try to import it into SQLDeveloper by right clicking to CONNECTIONS.

Answer (score 2):

To recover your password, locate the product_preferences.xml file in the following location:

C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system*\o.sqldeveloper\product-preferences.xml

Then, search for the string db.system.id and copy the value of the v attribute.  That is your decryption key to use when you are prompted to enter your decryption key on the Password Handling panel during the import processing on SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

for macOS

```
/Users/joseluisbz/.sqldeveloper/system18.1.0.095.1630/o.jdeveloper.db.connection/connections.xml
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/36775261/714112

Answer (score 1):

Linux: Tested with SQLDeveloper v22.2

`~/.sqldeveloper/system.x.y.z.yyy.ttt/o.jdeveloper.db.connection/connections.json` stores all the connections in json format.

To pretty-print it you can use:

```
jq . ~/.sqldeveloper/system.x.y.z.yyy.ttt/o.jdeveloper.db.connection/connections.json
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux systems:

`~/.sqldeveloper/system<sqldeveloper_version>/o.jdeveloper.db.connection/connections.xml`