# SQL Developer Connection through Socks 5 proxy

Tags: proxy, oracle-sqldeveloper, socks

I have been using SQL Developer v3.2.20 and it was working successfully with SecureCRT Dynamic port forwarding (socks 5 proxy) feature. Two parameters needs to be configured 
`AddVMOption -DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1
AddVMOption -DsocksProxyPort=21023`

Nowadays I am testing SQL Developer v4.0.3 (with jdk included ) and these parameters are not working. Do  I need to configure something else ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a relatively newer version of SQL Developer, one that ships with a 21c or higher JDBC Driver...

Create a SOCKS proxy using ssh

```
ssh -N -D 127.0.0.1:1080 user@ipaddress -o 'ProxyCommand=nc -X connect -x www-proxy.whatever.com:80 %h %p'
```

Now configure your SQL Developer connection to go through SOCKS proxy 127.0.0.1:1080.

On the connection details, go to the Advanced panel and set the following three JDBC driver connection properties:

1. oracle.net.socksProxyHost ([JDBC Driver Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_SOCKS_PROXY_HOST))
2. oracle.net.socksProxyPort
3. oracle.net.socksRemoteDNS

[image]

Match that up with what you've done on the local IP/port, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot but, I believe this would help someone else now :) 8 years but still something.

Comment: We had issues with that prevented making this easy/viable until just last year...sorry it took so long :(

Comment: This is per-connection, so if you have lots of connections on which you want to apply the specific setting you can open the file [connections.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76719655/1555615) on an editor and add copy paste the properties on each connection. But it would be good that you pretty-format the json file first (e.g. using an editor like vs-code)